# RSA - find d,e with restrictions

Tags: rsa, keys, key-generation

For academic purposes, assuming $n, p, q$  with $n\approx 2^{4096}$ and $p,q\approx 2^{2048}$.

I need to find ($e,d$) such that:

- $e$ is smaller than $2^{64}$
- $d\approx 2^{4096}$ and will have as much zeros as possible in binary form.
  ($d=$10000...0001 will be the best obviously, but I'm not greedy)

What will be the best way to find such a pair?

($n,p$ and $q$ are not fixed, if there is a way to find such $e,d$ by changing them then it is also a valid solution, as long as their lengths are as stated)

Comment: So you want $p$ and $q$ primes of about 2048-bit, odd $e$ at most 64-bit, with matching $d$ about 4096-bit and as sparse as feasible.  Are $p$ and $q$ free-to-choose? Is $p\ne q$ required? And what private exponent $d$ is/are acceptable? A) any $d$ that works, that is $e\cdot d\equiv1\pmod{\operatorname{LCM}(p-1,q-1)}$ B) The smallest $d$ that works, that is $d=e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{LCM}(p-1,q-1)$ C) That common one: $d=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))$

Comment: p and q are free to choose, p≠q is required.
and i'm looking for a d that match your (c) category.

Comment: I guess that fixing d, brute-forcing e, factoring e*d-1 until you get prime p and q of the desired size is feasible.

Comment: CodesInChaos - what do you mean "factoring e*d-1 until you get prime p and q"?

Comment: I think @CodesInChaos is thinking of choosing $d$ (perhaps the one you stated), trying various $e$, computing and trying to factor $e\,d-1$ (skipping quickly to the next $e$ if that factorization is hard to obtain or otherwise unusable); we know $\exists k,\ e\,d-1=k(p-1)(q-1)$, and from the factorization we can group factors so that $p-1$ and $q-1$ are about 2048-bit; with a moderate amount of luck (like, once in $(2048\log2)^2$) we'll get both $p$ and $q$ prime, done!

Comment: Choosing $d$ to be a special form ("as many zeros as possible in the binary representation") is likely to be a bad idea, at least, if you care about security.  Even if you pick from enough different $d$s to make a simple search infeasible, the special form is likely (in addition to the knowledge of $e$) to make factorization feasible.

Comment: Do you prioritize that $d$ _"will have as much zeros as possible in binary form"_, or keeping any security at all?. Also, the why of sparse $d=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))$ evades me: most RSA private-key implementations aiming at speed never raise to the power $d$ modulo $N$; rather they raise to the power $d\bmod(p-1)$ modulo $p$ and $d\bmod(q-1)$ modulo $q$, then use the CRT, then verify the result by raising it to the power $e$ modulo $N$. And even if they did use $d$, any about 4096-bit $d$ with $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{\operatorname{LCM}(p-1,q-1)}$ produces the correct result.

Comment: Also, if the reason you are looking for a low-hamming-weight $d$ is to improve performance, well, you might consider a windowed exponentiation routine, which gives about the same performance, and handles arbitrary exponents...